# How can I view log files in Linux and apply custom filers while viewing?

Tags: linux, log-files, filtering

(I asked [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338812/how-can-i-view-log-files-in-linux-and-apply-custom-filers-while-viewing) but it might be better off here...)

I need to read through some gigantic log files on a Linux system.  There's a lot of clutter in the logs.  At the moment I'm doing something like this:

```
cat logfile.txt | grep -v "IgnoreThis\|IgnoreThat" | less
```

But it's cumbersome -- every time I want to add another filter, I need to quit `less` and edit the command line.  Some of the filters are relatively complicated and may be multi-line.

I'd like some way to apply filters as I am reading through the log, and a way to save these filters somewhere.

Is there a tool that can do this for me?  I can't install new software so hopefully it's something that would already be installed -- e.g., less, vi, something in a Python or Perl lib, etc.

Changing the code that generates the log to generate less is not an option.

Comment: Dan, does it have to be a tool that works at the command line?

Comment: @William: No, but that would be preferred.  My biggest criteria is that it's something I already have installed -- of course you have no way of knowing that... I was hoping for some way `vi` could do this.  Someone suggested multitail on SO, looks good but I don't have it installed.

Answer (score 2):

1. Reading through large log files is not a good idea

   - you need to first filter them to the necessary lines and then look at them
   - even then, if possible (and if the filtered lines are a lot too),
     you should run secondary filters and counting scripts to analyze them
2. When you have a large static file and know the filters to eliminate lines from it,
   it is always a good idea to store the filtered output (rather than trying to look at it immediately).

   - This way you can run secondary filters on the filtered output and they will not need to run on the entire thing again
   - so, in your example, store the first output to a new file, and when you know another filter apply it on that stored file
   - of course, this implies some storage space for the filtered file.
     It works better if your filters will reduce the actual file by a large amount
3. Regular linux tool like '`grep`', `'sed`', '`AWK`' usually suffice to process text log file very nicely.
   I have processed log files in the order of 10GB frequently with these things.
   You can make your own tools with these things in '`bash scripts`'.
4. Don't underestimate '`vim`', it can handle large files too (but will take time, so give it filtered files)

Answer (score 0):

You certainly won't have this installed, but if this is going to be a regular thing you have to do it might be worth looking into [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com).  Splunk exists to index large datasets like this to help you find what you're looking for.